# Passing Instance Variables from a Controller to a Layout / .footer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I am in a dilemma, I'm new and I wonder if you can pass variables to .footer driver, and bootstrap use, chiro display data in a label.
This is the code of the controller:

```
class JuegosController < ApplicationController
load_and_authorize_resource param_method: :allowed_params, except: [:index, :show]

def index
    @juego = Juego.all


end

def show
    @juego = Juego.find(params[:id])



end

def new
    @juego = Juego.new      
end

def create
    @juego = Juego.new(allowed_params)
    if @juego.save
        redirect_to juegos_path
    else
        render 'new'            
    end
end

def edit
    @juego = Juego.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @juego = Juego.find(params[:id])
    if @juego.update_attributes(allowed_params)
        redirect_to juegos_path
    else
        redender 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    @juego = Juego.find(params[:id])
    @juego.destroy
    redirect_to juegos_path
end

private
    def allowed_params
        params.require(:juego).permit(:id_juego, :nombre, :descripcion, :numero_jugadores, :imagen )
    end
```

end

y este es el codigo del .footer :

```
  <footer class="footer" id="footer-new">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h4>ToyApp</h4>
          <p>
            <%= link_to 'Inicio',     page_path('home') %><br>
            <%= link_to 'Acerca de',  page_path('about') %><br>
            <%= link_to 'Contacto',   page_path('contact') %><br>
            <%= link_to 'Ayuda',      page_path('help') %><br>
            <%= link_to 'Términos',   page_path('terms') %>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

          <h4>Juegos</h4>
          <p>


          </p>

        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6" id="bottom-logo-block">
          <img src="assets/images/a.png" alt="" width="80" height="80">
          <p>
            es una marca registrada. Esta prohibido su uso<br>
          </p>
          <%= link_to 'Políticas de privacidad', page_path('privacy') %>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <br>
        <p>
        xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

My question is: how to display the name of a label or h1?

I tried with this but is not work :c

```
<h1><%= @juego.nombre %></h1>
```

Help me please, I am newbie.

Comment: That should work fine excepting `#index` since it is not a single instance. That being said if the footer is through out the application you would always have to have `@juego` defined with an instance of `Juego` or at least something that responds to `nombre`

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ugly-american-programmer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the footer is used across the application then you can look at using

**content_for / yield**

in the footer:

```
<h1><%= yield :footer_title %></h1>
```

in the view you can then set the title by controller / action something like

```
<% content_for :footer_title { @juego.nombre } %>
```

or

```
<% content_for :footer_title do %>
  Another title
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I use to render footer, and I mention it in <% = render 'layouts / footer'%> in aplication.html.erb. What I wonder: is it possible to call directly from the footer? The footer is in another folder called layout.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context in which the footer is being rendered. If the footer is being rendered within the context of a controller action in which `@juego` is defined then you should be able to call methods on the object. Two things though.

1) You are defining `@juego` differently in the different actions. In most of them it refers to a single object, whereas in the `index` method it refers to a collection of `@juego` objects. In this context, calling `@juego.nombre` will almost certainly fail.

2) This is bad practice. If your footer is global (i.e. if it is being shared between different contexts), then you should not be presuming that variable specific to a certain controller is always defined.